# Calculating mean of corresponding coefficient of three dimension data in R

Tags: r

I have this following output in R :

```
> out

, , 1

             Estimate Std. Error   z value     Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -0.8968692  0.1995274 -4.494968 6.958036e-06
X            0.5803202  0.2190155  2.649676 8.056901e-03
Z            0.2535625  0.2232445  1.135806 2.560376e-01
X:Z          0.3375088  0.2659863  1.268895 2.044784e-01

, , 2

              Estimate Std. Error   z value     Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -0.8624345  0.1888867 -4.565884 4.973944e-06
X            0.2544430  0.1784808  1.425604 1.539826e-01
Z            0.4704287  0.2387451  1.970423 4.878996e-02
X:Z          0.4813516  0.2239360  2.149505 3.159440e-02

, , 3

              Estimate Std. Error    z value     Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -1.0576301  0.1896436 -5.5769362 2.447916e-08
X            0.1515228  0.1917464  0.7902253 4.293962e-01
Z            0.1551839  0.2686790  0.5775810 5.635470e-01
X:Z          0.1673263  0.2872858  0.5824384 5.602714e-01
```

Now I want to compute the mean of  corresponding coefficients of estimates in this three replicate . That is , for intercept , the mean is (-0.8968692-0.8624345-1.0576301)/3 = -0.9389779

So I tried :

```
> out[1,,]
                    [,1]          [,2]          [,3]
Estimate   -8.968692e-01 -8.624345e-01 -1.057630e+00
Std. Error  1.995274e-01  1.888867e-01  1.896436e-01
z value    -4.494968e+00 -4.565884e+00 -5.576936e+00
Pr(>|z|)    6.958036e-06  4.973944e-06  2.447916e-08

mean(out[1,,])
[1] -1.406388
```

which is incorrect .

And then I tried as

```
 mean(out[1,,])$estimates
 Error in mean(out[1, , ])$estimates : 
 $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

How can I compute the mean of the corresponding estimates ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` for this. Here's a reproducible example.

```
set.seed(357)
xy <- array(runif(27), dim = c(3, 3, 3))
xy

, , 1

           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.10728121 0.2248621 0.9337365
[2,] 0.05504568 0.6534852 0.7474587
[3,] 0.27987766 0.4634314 0.7783997

, , 2

          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.9913409 0.4601817 0.1716801
[2,] 0.6245529 0.2254525 0.3195294
[3,] 0.5245744 0.5898001 0.8953055

, , 3

          [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.6831485 0.45645455 0.7077218
[2,] 0.4317410 0.36626006 0.6886439
[3,] 0.1809770 0.04334935 0.3717553

mean(c(0.107, 0.991, 0.683))

[1] 0.5936667

apply(xy, MARGIN = 1:2, FUN = mean)

          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.5939235 0.3804995 0.6043794
[2,] 0.3704465 0.4150659 0.5852107
[3,] 0.3284764 0.3655270 0.6818202
```

Or you can use `rowMeans`

```
  t(apply(xy, 1, FUN=rowMeans))
  #         [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
  #[1,] 0.5939235 0.3804995 0.6043794
  #[2,] 0.3704465 0.4150659 0.5852107
  #[3,] 0.3284764 0.3655270 0.6818202
```

Comment: `rowMeans(xy, dims = 2)`

Comment: @Roland that looks like it could be very efficient. Want to make some timings?

Comment: Sorry, but I have to run now. There is a festival starting today and I need to hit the road. Feel free to benchmark it.